# "Cannot return a value from a method with void result type" but it's not void?

Tags: java

In Java, I'm getting the error for all my return statements that I can't return a value with a void result type, but I don't declare the return type as void anywhere, and I'm really not sure what the issue is. Here's my code:

public class Card {

```
private int suit;
private int rank;

public Card(int suit, int rank) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;

public String toString() {
    String[] suits = {"clubs", "diamonds", "spades", "hearts"};
    String[] ranks = {"non-existing-rank", "A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
    return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
}

public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public boolean equals(Card other) {
    // Two cards are equal only if they have the same suit and the same rank.
    return suit == other.suit && rank == other.rank;
}

public int compareTo(Card other) {
    // First compare the suit, and only if the suit is the same compare the rank.
    if (suit < other.suit) {
        return -1;
    } else if (suit > other.suit) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (rank < other.rank) {
            return -1;
        } else if (rank > other.rank) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the paranthesis in the Card() constructor:

```
public Card(int suit, int rank) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
} // missed
```

Other than that everything is fine.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much...

Comment: Some numpty gave you a downvote. Fixed it.